# Dynamically Adding MIME type to Microsoft IIS Server

Tags: iis, mime-types, iis-6

I'm attempting to add a MIME type without opening inetmgr and adding it in there. The reason for this is our IIS setup is part of an image that I would prefer not to edit.

I added the information for the new MIME type to the web.config under the System.webServer tag.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lz4" mimeType="application/lz4" />
</staticContent>
```

I was hoping that IIS would pick this up and add it to the MIME list, but when I open the inetmgr, I do not see "lz4" in the list. Is it possible to even have IIS pick up a new MIME type like this or at all?

Comment: In IIS Manager which list did you open for MIME types? If you try to add new types in `web.config`, you can only see them added in site or app level for that `web.config` file, not at server level.

Comment: I added it to the server level web.config so I figured that would work. I didn't try adding it to the site level. Will site level include virtual directories?

Comment: “The server level web.config” does not exist, so I really wonder what file you did change actually.

Comment: I'm new at IIS, I have done tomcat with War files before so this is all brand new.

I seem to have a web.config at my root web site folder, then there are a few others: one in a subfolder named "bin" and another in a subfolder named "View".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Learn some basic IIS concepts then. Sounds like you added the types at site level, then you should be able to see them for that site at site level at least. All applications under that site should inherit the new settings.

Comment: I set a basic "hello world" site up on my laptop, external to the actual one we run in our image using that page. So I have the bare basics at least lol. I'll have to try it in that project to see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I think this document might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: There is no <mimeMap> element in IIS6. The <mimeMap> element of the <staticContent> element was introduced in IIS 7.0.